# Where to put setup/teardown in Go Benchmarks?

Tags: go

I have a go test file in which I wrote a benchmark function as follows:

```
func BenchmarkStuff(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        stuff()
    }
}
```

However the `stuff()` function requires some setup to occur every time before it runs and cleanup to occur every time after it runs. I have functions `setup()` and `cleanup()` that do this respectively. But I don't want to benchmark the setup and cleanup functions.

So where should they be called? If I call them inside BenchmarkStuff, they will be added to the results measurements. But without them, `stuff()` will fail.

Comment: If that's the case, you have to call them inside the benchmark, because the benchmark needs to call `stuff()` `b.N` times.

Comment: That would mean putting those calls inside the loop. 
But if I do that, how will I see the timing data for `stuff()` separate from `cleanup()` and `setup()`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The benchmarking package provides [`ResetTimer`](https://pkg.go.dev/testing#B.ResetTimer), [`StopTimer`](https://pkg.go.dev/testing#B.StopTimer) and [`StartTimer`](https://pkg.go.dev/testing#B.StartTimer) methods to avoid timing initialization needed for the benchmark.

If initialization is needed once, use `ResetTimer` before starting your loop:

```
func BenchmarkStuff(b *testing.B) {
    setup()
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        stuff()
    }
}
```

If you need to re-initialize during the loop, you can use `StopTimer` and `StartTimer` to avoid timing that portion:

```
func BenchmarkStuff(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        b.StopTimer()
        setup()
        b.StartTimer()
        stuff()
    }
}
```